# How to perform Grid Search on a multi-label classification problem?

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, grid-search, multiclass-classification, gridsearchcv

I am learning Scikit-Learn and I am trying to perform a grid search on a multi label classification problem. This is what I wrote:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

param_grid = [
    {'randomforestclassifier__n_estimators': [3, 10, 30], 'randomforestclassifier__max_features': [2, 4, 5, 8]},
    {'randomforestclassifier__bootstrap': [False], 'randomforestclassifier__n_estimators': [3, 10], 'randomforestclassifier__max_features': [2, 3, 4]}
]

rf_classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(
    make_pipeline(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42))
)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(rf_classifier, param_grid=param_grid, cv=5, scoring = 'f1_micro')
grid_search.fit(X_train_prepared, y_train)
```

However when I run it I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter randomforestclassifier for estimator 
OneVsRestClassifier(estimator=Pipeline(steps=[('randomforestclassifier',
RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42))])). Check the list of available parameters 
with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

I tried to run also the `grid_search.estimator.get_params().keys()` command but I just get a list of parameters containing the ones that I have written, therefore I am not sure what I should do.

Would you be able to suggest what the issue is and how I can run the grid search properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have been able to define `param_grid` as you did in case `rf_classifier` was a `Pipeline` object. Quoting the Pipeline's docs

> The purpose of the pipeline is to assemble several steps that can be cross-validated together while setting different parameters. ***For this, it enables setting parameters of the various steps using their names and the parameter name separated by a '__'***.

In your case, instead, `rf_classifier` is `OneVsRestClassifier` instance. Therefore, before setting the parameters for the RFC, you'll need to be able to  access the pipeline instance, which you can do via [`OneVsRestClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html) `estimator`'s parameter, as follows:

```
param_grid = [
    {'estimator__randomforestclassifier__n_estimators': [3, 10, 30], 
     'estimator__randomforestclassifier__max_features': [2, 4, 5, 8]
    },
    {'estimator__randomforestclassifier__bootstrap': [False], 
     'estimator__randomforestclassifier__n_estimators': [3, 10], 
     'estimator__randomforestclassifier__max_features': [2, 3, 4]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! That was briliant!! :)